# Asp.net Core RC2 how to disable Transfer-Encoding: chunked on response

Tags: http, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm having issues with certain http clients (Matlab and KDB) having problems with chunked http responses.

Is there a way to disable chunked responses in Kestrel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the content-length for responses. This may require buffering.