# Invalid characters on response body

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm migrating an existing MVC5 json webservice to AspNet Core RC2 running on full framework (NET 4.6.1).

Every controller inherits from _BaseController:

```
public class _BaseController : Controller
{
   public IActionResult Success(object data) { return Json({ IsSuccess = true, Data = data }); }
   public IActionResult Error(string message) { return Json({ IsSuccess = false, Message = message }); }
}
```

This is a sample controller:

```
public class SampleController : _BaseController
{
   public IActionResult Something() { return Success(new { FirstItem = "First", SecondItem = "Second", ThirdItem = 1 }); }
}
```

On RC1 this worked fine. Response was just fine.

After updating to RC2, the JSON response now contains some strange/invalid chars.

From Fiddler, this is the original (valid) response:

```
{"isSuccess":true,"data":{"firstItem":"first","secondItem":"second","thirdItem":1}}
```

But RC2 delivers an invalid response like this (full raw response from Fiddler which is the same as received by .NET winforms client):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2016 20:38:55 GMT

3de
{"sucesso":true,"dados":{"codigo":1,"dataUltimaAtualizacao":"2016-06-27T00:00:00","horaUltimaAtualizacao":"17:18:06.8099844","offsetHoraUltimaAtualizacao":-180,"cnpj":"23303829000169","razaoSocial":"NACIONAL SOFT LTDA","nomeFantasia":"NACIONAL SOFT","tipoEstabelecimento":"MATRIZ","inicioAtividade":"1987-05-13T00:00:00","atividadePrimaria":"62.03-1-00 - Desenvolvimento e licenciamento de programas de computador não-customizáveis","atividadesSecundarias":"62.02-3-00 - Desenvolvimento e licenciamento de programas de computador customizáveis","naturezaJuridica":"206-2 - SOCIEDADE EMPRESARIA LIMITADA","logradouro":"R HORTENCIA","numero":"591","complemento":"CONJUNTO 01","bairro":"ESPLANADA","municipio":"BELO HORIZONTE","uf":"MG","cep":"30280250","enderecoEletronico":"","telefone":"","enteFederativoResponsavel":"*****","situacaoCadastral":"ATIVA","dataSituacaoCadastral":"2005-11-03T00:00:00","motivoSituacaoCadastral":"","situacaoEspecial":"********","dataSituacaoEspecial":null}}
0
```

This is driving me crazy here. Does anyone have any idea if it's related to integration between Kestrel and IIS? Any clue at all?

Comment: Looks like a chunked response, where the payload is actually 990 bytes (3de hex)) and the last `o` will actually be a `0` (zero). Is this a problem for the consuming application?

Comment: Yup, it's a 0, my bad. This is an issue because when I read from the response stream, those chars are there and json won't parse.

Comment: Is that JSON you show really the actual payload? If so, then there might be a bug in how chunk length is calculated (apart from chunking being pretty useless for such a response).

Comment: Now with real payload. Same idea as before, but with a much larger json.
`SampleController` basically creates this object (concrete class) and returns as Json(data).

Comment: So it is a valid chunked response, and the actual response length is actually 990 bytes (0x3DE hex). No bug. The problem is in your client code. See [Asp.net Core RC2 how to disable Transfer-Encoding: chunked on response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839877/asp-net-core-rc2-how-to-disable-transfer-encoding-chunked-on-response) if you can't fix your client, not sure if that works though.

Comment: Fine, I can try to fix client code. But why it wasn't chuncked ever before (MVC3, MVC4, MVC5 and RC1) and now on RC2 it gets chuncked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's all about chuncked response as CodeCaster commented.

I'll try and fix the client as well but [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839877/asp-net-core-rc2-how-to-disable-transfer-encoding-chunked-on-response) has a fix for this.

So, if anyone runs into this again, just add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Buffering` on `package.json` and this line on `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseResponseBuffering();
```